# The code of the component is unreachable although is getting the dynamic route param

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi people  I am doing a project with React + JS and I have installed wouter and I am trying to make my app working with a dynamic params in the route. That means: if I go to "`/gif/panda`" that it will render the gifs of pandas. However, although I have been several hours researching, I dont know what happens. As you can see in console, the "`/gif/:keyword/`", I mean, the `keyword` is received by the component `List of Gifs`, as it returns the phrase "Hola Panda". Panda was the keyword. But I dont know why the return code of the component is unreacheable and, therefore, the app crashes. Any idea? Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put JSX code into brackets on return statement.(in ListofGifs component)
Since there is no brackets your function returns nothing. If you look carefully you can see that the code after return statement is pale which means it just doesn't work. I added image below. I hope it solves problem.

[add brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCR6S.png)